# What would be a way working with layout weight

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

> I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3996104/2255924).  I planned to do like this:

[image]

> But it showing in this way:

[image]

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHiragana"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hiragana"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvKanji"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kanji"
        android:textColor="@color/redColor"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What should I do make it work correct in the terms of `layout_weight`? How to avoid making new lines in TextView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What should I do make it work correct in the terms of layout_weight?

First, when using `weight` with a `horizontal` layout, your `width` should be `0dp`. Similarly, if your layout is `vertical` then your `height` should be `0dp`.

> How to avoid making new lines in TextView?

use `android:singleLine="true"` if you want to

> Constrains the text to a single horizontally scrolling line instead of letting it wrap onto multiple lines

[TextView Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3asingleLine)

If this doesn't answer your question then please be a little more clear because its a bit confusing on what you're asking.

Comment: First, when using weight with a horizontal layout, your width should be 0dp

Comment: Where I should put 0dp inside layout or textview?

Comment: Your `TextView`s each should have `android:layout_width="0dp"`

Comment: Error integer types not allowed: <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvKanji"
            android:layout_width="0"